# How to work with classes of pecl_http module in localhost

Tags: php, http, pecl

I am on MAC OS X El Capitan with PHP version 5.5.31 and installed pecl_http version 2.5.5 module on my local server. 
When I am trying to create objects of following classes on my localhost

```
http\Client
http\Client\Request
http\Message\Body
```

I am getting following error

```
The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Has anyone had a similar experience? Please suggest the steps I need to follow to make the pecl_http module classes to work on my localhost.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help tremendously if you could produce some logs and describe the way you installed PHP and pecl::http.

Comment: I followed this https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-osx-10-11-el-capitan/ to get Apache, MySQL, PHP and phpMyAdmin working on OSX 10.11 El Capitan.

I installed pear, pecl, autoconf, raphf-1.1.2 & then installed the pecl_http( as 2.5.5 version of pecl_http is compatible with PHP 5.5.31 ) by following command.

sudo pecl install pecl_http-2.5.5

Comment: This is really too little info to pinpoint the issue. My *guess* is that the module isn't properly configured and/or loaded by Apache. c&p relevant parts (if any) of Apache's error log or you will likely never receive an answer.